# <NoErrorObjectAvailable> Script error in lightning web component (LWC)

Tags: javascript, html, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to create a customer review form but having issues when the user is about to submit it.

Whenever I try to test by clicking the submit button, I keep getting the error below,

[image: errorscreenshot of the error message]

Where could I have gone wrong?

My code can be found below (HTML, then Javascript)

```html
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Customer_Review__c" onsubmit={handleSubmit} record-id={recordId}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Hotel_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Price_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Staff_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Room_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Event_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Equipment_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Environment_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Manager_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Cocktail_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Drink_Rating__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button type="submit" label="Submit Review"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Marriott extends LightningElement {
    @api
    handleSubmit(event) {
        // Prevent the form from being submitted
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the form element
        const form = event.target;

        // Get the values of the form fields
        const values = {};
        for (let field of form.elements) {
            if (field.name) {
                values[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        }

        // Output the form values to the console
        console.log(values);

        // Clear the form fields
        form.reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code of `handleSubmit` in a try catch block and `console.log` the error. This is helpful in debugging the `NoErrorObjectAvailable` error. Is handle submit being used outside the Marionette class. It is defined as an api method

Try replacing

```
const form = event.target;
```

with

```
const fields = event.detail.fields
```

and loop over fields instead of `form.elements`

Since this is supported by `lightning-record-edit-form`'s submit event and you want to loop over the fields.